# Is the $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ equivalent?

Tags: complex-analysis, curves

> Determine whether the following pairs of paths are rectifiable and equivalent: $\gamma_1:[0,2\pi]\to\Bbb C$, given by $\gamma_1(t)=e^{it}$ for each $t\in[0,2\pi]$, and $\gamma_2:[0,4\pi]\to\Bbb C$, given by $\gamma_2(t)=e^{it}$ for each $t\in[0,4\pi]$.

I managed to show that these two paths are rectifiable. I am having difficulty in showing the equivalence part.

I tried to find a change of parameter $\phi$, but I cannot find one. I tried the $\phi(t)=t/2$, but this doesn't work since it doesn't satisfy $\gamma_2=\gamma_1\circ\phi$.

Could someone kindly help? Thanks so much!

Comment: What does equivalent means here?

Comment: @JohnMa It means there is a change of parameter $\phi$ which is continuous strictly increasing and surjective from $[0,4\pi]$ to $[0,2\pi]$ and $\phi(0)=0,\phi(4\pi)=2\pi$ such that $\gamma_2(t)=\gamma_1\circ\phi$.